# Match exact number and string with anything within both

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb

I want to match the string "**108 Mobile Fist**" with the following searches:

- 108
- 108 Fist
- 108 Mobile

How can I achieve this using RexExp?

Right now I'm using `/^.*108.*.Fist.*/ig`, but this doesn't work.

Comment: `/^.*108.*.(Fist|Mobile).*/ig` or `/^108 (Fist|Mobile)$/ig`

Comment: Try this regex `/^108( Mobile)?( Fist)?/ig`

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi No, that would allow for `108 Mobile Fist`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I thought he wants to list if he searches with full text. My bad if I understood wrongly.

Comment: Actually, the words may vary

Comment: @Maskter what is desired result result when search is `108 Mobile Fist`   ?

Comment: @CodeManiac i want to be able to find 108 Mobile Fist searching 108, 108 Fist or 108 Mobile

Comment: @Maskter: My previous regex should work for you and it will additionally allow `108 Mobile Fist`. If you don't want that additional text then how about `/^108(?: Mobile| Fist)?/` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your RegExp code and the mistake is you used `.*` which means everything in the string so i suggest to use this symbol `.` carefully because it means all letters so i suggest this instead yours:-

```
/^\s?108\s?(?:Mobile\sFist)?(?:Mobile)?(?:Fist)?/ig
```

Comment: Whats the use of \s?

Comment: It means space.